# Let $L/\Bbb{Q}_p$ be ramification index $e$ extension. Let $π$ be prime element of $L$. Then, why $p＝π^eu$(u:unit element of ring of integers of $L$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $L/\Bbb{Q}_p$ be ramification index $e$ extension. Let $π$ be prime element of $L$.
Then, why $p＝π^eu$ ($u$: unit element of ring of integers of $L$)?
From the definition of ramification index,

$(p)＝(π)^e$

Thus, $(p)＝(π^e)$

From here, why can we say $p＝π^eu$ ($u$:unit element of ring of integers of $L$)?

Comment: This is quite the definition of $(a)=(b)\ne \{0\}$ in an integral domain: $b\in (a)$ iff $b/a\in R$, and $a\in (b)$ gives that $a/b\in R$ as well. $(p)=(\pi)^e$ is the definition of $e$. $(\pi)$ is the prime ideal of $O_L$ not $L$.

Comment: You seem to suppose $a$ and $b$ are units. If not, what is the definition of $b/a$ and $a/b$?

Comment: Elements of the fraction field